# How is 10%-3 -2 in python? Please explain

Tags: python, modulo

I am not able to understand how is 10%-3 -2 in python? I am a beginner who just started learning python. Please explain

Answer (score -2):

It is a question of math, the evaluation is like this, (10) % (-3), and if you input this into any calculator, it will give you -2. Try typing *10 modulo -3* on Google and see the result

Comment: The rules aren't that strictly defined with negative operands. [It can just as easily produce `1`](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCVVwaa4JCUzXy/Djiszr0QhNzEzT0NToZpLAQgKioBCaRpKqikxeUo6CoYGCqoKusaa1ly1//8DAA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online"). Python has specifically defined modulus to work this way, that's all.